# Implement dynamic chart which update every second in iOS

Tags: ios, charts, highcharts

I'm trying to implement the chart which update every second in iOS.

```
import UIKit
import Highcharts
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore
import Charts

class LiveTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var Aitime: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var time: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var nowusdt: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var nowq8: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var inusdt: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var live: LineChartView!
@IBOutlet weak var Number: UILabel!
let db = Firestore.firestore()
var number: Int = 0 {
    didSet {
        Number.text = "#"+String(number)
        
    }
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    
    // Configure the view for the selected state
}



func LiveChart(quantity: Double,lastQuatityTimestamp: Int){
    let chartView = HIChartView(frame: live.bounds)


        let options = HIOptions()

        let chart = HIChart()
        chart.type = "spline"
        chart.marginRight = 10

        chart.events = HIEvents()
    
        chart.events.load = HIFunction(jsFunction: "function () { var series = this.series[0]; setInterval(function () { var x = (new Date()).getTime(), y = \(quantity); series.addPoint([x, y], true, true); }, 1000); }")
        options.chart = chart

        let time = HITime()
        time.useUTC = true
        options.time = time

        let title = HITitle()
        title.text = "Live random data"
        options.title = title

        let accessibility = HIAccessibility()
        accessibility.announceNewData = HIAnnounceNewData()
        accessibility.announceNewData.enabled = true
        accessibility.announceNewData.minAnnounceInterval = 15000
        accessibility.announceNewData.announcementFormatter = HIFunction(jsFunction: "function (allSeries, newSeries, newPoint) { if (newPoint) { return 'New point added. Value: ' + newPoint.y; } return false; }")
        options.accessibility = accessibility

        let xAxis = HIXAxis()
        xAxis.type = "datetime"
        xAxis.tickPixelInterval = 150
        options.xAxis = [xAxis]

        let yAxis = HIYAxis()
        yAxis.title = HITitle()
        yAxis.title.text = "Value"
        let plotLines = HIPlotLines()
        plotLines.value = 0
        plotLines.width = 1
        plotLines.color = HIColor(hexValue: "808080")
        yAxis.plotLines = [plotLines]
        options.yAxis = [yAxis]

        let tooltip = HITooltip()
        tooltip.headerFormat = "<b>{series.name}</b><br/>"
        tooltip.pointFormat = "{point.x:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}<br/>{point.y:.2f}"
        options.tooltip = tooltip

        let legend = HILegend()
        legend.enabled = false
        options.legend = legend

        let exporting = HIExporting()
        exporting.enabled = false
        options.exporting = exporting

        let spline = HISpline()
        spline.name = "Random data"

        spline.data = [

            ["x": Int64((Date().timeIntervalSince1970)),"y": 20],
            ["x": Date().timeIntervalSince1970],
            ["x": Date().timeIntervalSince1970]

        ]
    
        options.series = [spline]

        chartView.options = options

        self.live.addSubview(chartView)

   } 
}
```

Through this class from the beginning when the chart rendered, it rendered perfectly but after that for the some couple of seconds, it's line is not rendered perfectly and again after some couple of seconds, it is working fine and update every second.

I want to implement the chart that is in X-axis, it start from the lastQuatityTimestamp which is the parameter in LiveChart function and after that it start from the current time and update for every second.

Chart in the X-axis start from the 1975 for some second and after that it is working fine but I need to start from the lastQuatityTimestamp and after that it start from the current time.
[VideoLink](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L_-VuEuqyg8mwiqstjeckY-AEv2IeCQa/view?usp=share_link)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, It seems to be something wrong with your data - there is a lack of `y` for two points:

```
spline.data = [

            ["x": Int64((Date().timeIntervalSince1970)),"y": 20],
            ["x": Date().timeIntervalSince1970],
            ["x": Date().timeIntervalSince1970]

        ]
```

You need to multiply `Date().timeIntervalSince1970` by 1000, to overlap with `Date()).getTime()` in JS.

Then, set the starting date to:

```
spline.data = [
   ["x": Date().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000, "y": lastQuatityTimestamp]
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I am having real time data on Firestore which I need to show on the graph but everytime its taking the very first value and graph looks flat. I want graph to respond to updated value. I hope I am able to explain my question

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. When it comes to the adding point, you can use `addPoint` at the series object. 
`let data = HIData()
data.x = Date().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000 as NSNumber
data.y = 0.2583323455534311
series.addPoint(data) // spline` . So, you need to remove `chart.events = HIEvents()
chart.events.load = HIFunction(jsFunction: "function () { var series = this.series[0]; setInterval(function () { var x = (new Date()).getTime(), y = Math.random(); series.addPoint([x, y], true, true); }, 1000); }")` and add `series.addPoint` when it is needed

Comment: If we remove the code snippet as you said so where we need to declare series for adding series.addPoint

Comment: You have already declared the series `let spline = HISpline()`, so the only thing left to do is to implement a timer that will add new points